# Describing a displacement

Tags: motion-verbs

1. A friend of mine told me I cannot tell **"Страна, куда я поехал"**
   rather than **"Страна, куда я ездил"**. Even when I am referring to
   a completed trip which just happened once (*"The country I went to
   in November"*, for example). 
   Is the imperfective indeterminate verb a requirement of **куда**
   itself?
2. I want to say "We need to travel at least 2000 kms if we want to go somewhere beyond (to the east) of France". Is it OK to tell **"Нам приходится доехать минимум 2000 км если мы собираемся поехать куда-либо дальше (на востоке от) Франции"**?

Comment: In #1 both variants are OK. In #2, "приходится доехать" should be changed either into "придётся проехать" or into "нужно проехать". Also, "на востоке от" means location, but you'd want direction, that's why it must be changed into "на восток от". And a comma is needed before "если".

Comment: #1A "Страна, куда я поехал" - is good if you are telling a story about your trip. #2B "Страна, куда я ездил" is context-neutral and is generally good.

Comment: 1) Both are possible depending on context. _Куда я ездил_ - strictly implies that past. _Куда я поехaл_ may even imply the present if you are physically present in some country and are telling someone about your being there at the moment (you 've come there and are telling about it). 
2) not quite clear why (to the east) in parentheses, hence confusion.

Comment: I didn't get the thing about France. There are plenty of other countries to the east of France and closer than 2000 km.

Comment: @AlexVB It could depend on the context. If you start in Portugal and/or have a complex travel plan, you will need to travel more than 2000 kms to cross the eastern border of France.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between поехал and eздил is similar to that of "have gone" and "have been" both deriving from the verb "go". Поехал means you are still there, ездил means you visited and returned.

> "We need to travel at least 2000 kms if we want to go somewhere beyond (to the east) of France". Is it OK to tell "Нам приходится доехать минимум 2000 км если мы собираемся поехать куда-либо дальше (на востоке от) Франции"?

Almost correct. Нам придется(future) проехать(cover), как минимум,2000 км, если мы собираемся поехать куда‐либо дальше, восточнее/на восток от Франции.